# PasteSpecial method of Range class Failed on second run of Macro

Tags: excel, vba

First off I am not a coder.  I am trying to get a section of this code to increment the column number each time the macro is run.  It works the first time then has the Range class error the next run.  Also my incrementing doesn't appear to be working either.  Here is the complete code with the section giving the error pointed out:

```
Sub Prep_Report_Rev_B()
'
' Prep_Report_Rev_B Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'

' Declare Variables

Dim xdate As Date
Dim incCol As Integer

' Ensure button not pressed multiple times a day

    xdate = Worksheets("Summary").Range("F6")

    If Month(Date) = Month(xdate) And Year(Date) = Year(xdate) And Day(Date) = Day(xdate) Then
        MsgBox "Report can only be run once per day to prevent data loss"
        GoTo Line1
    End If

' Copy Data to Historical Tab
'  ** Need to increment column number **

    If incCol = 0 Then
        incCol = 1
    Else
        incCol = incCol + 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "0000"
    Range("L3:L8,L11:L15,L18:L22,L34:L38,L41:L45,L57:L61,L64:L68").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "0000"

' =========================================================================
    Cells(2, incCol).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=False ' <----
' ==========================================================================

    ActiveSheet.Protect "0000"

' Enter current Date on "Summary" Page

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("F6") = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ActiveSheet.Protect "0000"

' Clear "Previous Service Report Data" tab

    Sheets("Previous Service Report Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "0000"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

' Copy data from "Service Report" to "Previous Service Report"

    Sheets("Service Report Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "0000"
    Columns("A:AK").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Previous Service Report Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect "0000"

' Clear "Service Report Data" to prepare for new data

    Sheets("Service Report Data").Select
    Columns("A:AI").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect "0000"

' Pull Up webpage

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="google.com"

Line1:

End Sub
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to make sure your destination range is the same shape/size as your origin.

Comment: After your subroutine completes `incCol` is tossed and has no value anymore. When you run this a second time, it's just going to be zero again. If you need to store this value somewhere, I'd suggest in a hidden cell in your worksheet, or if you're trying to run this multiple times, just increment it within a `Loop`.

Comment: Thank you @dwirony.  The incCol in now incrementing with each button press.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  The initial range has cells I don't want to copy, and on the new sheet, I want the data together.  Is there a way to do that?  Sorry if this is a noob question.
  @BruceWayne

Comment: As a side comment, `And` only operates on *two* conditions. At the beginning, when you're comparing the dates, you're not getting a true comparison. I learned this the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, it will move the selected range into a new range. This code should select your range and move it to the Historical Data Sheet. Make sure to change the name on `set sh = wb.Sheets("NAME OF YOUR SHEET")`  to the name of your sheet. I would probably create a test sheet for both to test them to make sure they are doing what you want them to do and you don't mess up your data.

```
Dim sh As worksheet
Dim sh1 As worksheet
Dim rng, rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6 As range


set wb = ThisWorkbook
set sh = wb.Sheets("NAME OF YOUR SHEET")
set sh1 = wb.Sheets("NAME OF SHEET YOU WANT TO COPY TO")
set rng = sh.Range("L3:L8")
set rng1 = sh.Range("L11:L15")
set rng2 = sh.Range("L18:L22")
set rng3 = sh.Range("L34:L38")
set rng4 = sh.Range("L41:L45")
set rng5 = sh.range("L57:L61")
set rng6 = sh.range("L64:L68")


sh1.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

sh1.range("B1").Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng1.Cells.Value

sh1.range("C1").Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, rng2.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng2.Cells.Value

sh1.range("D1").Resize(rng3.Rows.Count, rng3.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng3.Cells.Value

sh1.range("E1").Resize(rng4.Rows.Count, rng4.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng4.Cells.Value

sh1.range("F1").Resize(rng5.Rows.Count, rng5.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng5.Cells.Value

sh1.range("G1").Resize(rng6.Rows.Count, rng6.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng6.Cells.Value
```

Edit - I kind of spelled it out for you in hope if you need to make changes its easy to see what the code is doing, there is probably a better way to do this with less code but this way you are not using copy and paste it just transfers the data and is much faster. I set each range to the first row in each column. To change where you the data is placed just change the location after the `sh1.range("G1")`

Comment: Thank you @Trog.  For some reason, this is only copying the first range L3:L8.

Comment: I may have typed something wrong.  I tried the way you posted going to a designated cell, and this way (to increment the cell):                      
                      sh1.Cells(2, incCol).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value                                 Both only copied the first range.

Comment: Okay we might have to break out each range.